# check numeric value of a text box Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery 1.3.2

Both codes are use to check numeric value of a text box.  not working in Mobile browser

**.qty class uis dynamic generate.

Code 1:

```
<script>
    $(".qty").live('keydown', function (event) {

        $(".qty").numeric();

    });

</script>
```

Code 2:

```
<script>
    $(".qty").live('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) {

            }
            else {

                if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

Please Help

Comment: Try using [which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/).

Comment: try event.which and return false

Comment: Not working Chrome browser in Mobile @Devjit

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var cc = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode); 
if ((cc > 47 && cc < 58) || cc == 43 || cc == 44 || cc == 45 || cc == 40 || cc == 41 || cc == 32 || cc == 46 || cc == 8 || cc == 127 || cc == 9) {
        return true;
}
return false;
```